# what is a spectral function?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, spectral-theory

My knowledge in spectral theory is very limited, but lately I heard talking about the spectral function of an operator and how it's important. By curiosity I tried to look for a definition and a meaning  of it on the internet but unfortunally I found nothing only spectral functions of some specific operators but no general definition ! even in some books about spectral theory I search for this mathematical object but in vain.

Can any one give me a reference where I can find such definition or maybe the definition itself ? My second question is why such function is important and what does it mean? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

This is linked with the spectral theorem. There are multiple formulations of this powerful theorem, one is the following :

> **Spectral theorem (multiplication operator form) :**
>
> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and $A\in\mathcal{L}\left(\mathcal{H}\right)$, that is, $A$ is a linear bounded mapping $\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$. Then there is a measure space $\left(\Omega,\mu\right)$ with $\mu\left(\Omega\right)<+\infty$, there is an unitary mapping $U:\mathcal{H}\to L^2\left(\Omega,\mu\right)$ and there is a bounded function $F:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ such that
>   $$UAU^{-1}f(x)=F(x)f(x)\quad\quad\forall f\in L^2\left(\Omega,\mu\right),\forall x\in\Omega.$$

$\mu$ is called the **spectral measure** and $F$ the **spectral function**. In a certain way, we can *diagonalize* $A$ on another space as we do for linear operators in finite dimension : $A$ is said to be a multiplication in $L^2$. $L^p$ spaces are well knowed and studied, especially for the case $p=2$ (it is an Hilbert space in this case), so a multiplication on it is easier to deal with rather than an operator on an abstract Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

A very good reference to begin is the book "Methods of modern mathematical physics" by Reed & Simon. The above theorem is in the first volume.

Comment: I think it is $[UAf](x) = F(x) [Uf](x) $ ? think to $U$ as the Fourier transform and the linear operator being the convolution by a filter $h(x)$, then $F$ is the Fourier transform of $h$

Comment: @reuns In the above formulation, it is $UAU^{-1}f(x)=F(x)f(x)$ ($U^{-1}$ takes an argument in $L^2$ and gives an element of $\mathcal{H}$).

Comment: ok it's a weird formulation, $f$ is not the element of the hilbert space of which $A$ acts. I think $[U A f](x) = F(x) [U f](x)$ is much easier to understand.

Comment: and do you have theorems on "how looks the eigenvalue space" ? sometimes it is isomorphic to the Hilbert space, sometimes it is countable ?

Comment: @reuns Maybe it is easier to see it as a diagonalization : if $A$ is a matrix that can be diagonalized, then you can write $PAP^{-1}=D$ with $P$ a matrix of passage and $D$ a diagonal one. So if $v$ is an eigenvector associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we can write $PAP^{-1}v=\lambda v$. In the spectral theorem, $U$ acts as $P$, $F$ as $\lambda$.

Comment: I do not know any general theorem about how to describe the spectral measures/functions ; this kind of questions is to handle for each operator alone.

Comment: I know what the spectral theorem is, but your formulation isn't adapted to, in pratice, simplify a complicated linear operator into an unitary transform plus multiplication by a constant vector. I prefer my formulation which is adapted to the Fourier transform / convolution example, which is the reason why at first Hilbert spaces and spectral theorem for Hilbert space operators were studied. (the Fourier transform  being linked to diffential equations)

Comment: @reuns Oh you talk about your above formulation. It is indeed worth to formulate the problem in way that can simplify the situation. Anyway, there are many formulations of the spectral theorem.

Comment: I told you before : $[UAf](x)=F(x)[Uf](x)$ where $f$ is an element of the Hilbert space $H$, $A: H \to H$, and $F$ belongs to the eigenvalue space of $A$, $U$ is an unitary transform $H \to H$ (which means $U U^* = Id$). and this is why we need precision on that eigenvalue space.

Comment: no in fact $U$ is not an unitary operator, it is a projection operator from $H$ to $E$ the space of eigenvalues, and $U^* U = Id_E$. this way we see the "rank" of the linear operator as the rank of it's eigenvector space. If you don't allow $U$ being a projection operator, you cannot explain what for example the Fourier series, without studying at first the distributions space, dual to the Hilbert space.